# Fetch replies with Java Mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I have an email server to which people reply from emails that have been sent to them from that mail server.
Then I want to fetch these replies using the Java Mail API, but I am running into problems.

I am trying to fetch the replies via a `ReceivedDateTerm` and an hourly cron, thus fetching all the replies in the last hour.
Let's say someone replied to an email sent to them yesterday at 3 p.m., today at 10 a.m. If I search for all emails since 9 a.m. today, I don’t get any results. However, if I search for all emails since yesterday 2 p.m., I get that reply, including the original email.

If I look into the reply (the `Message` object), the `receivedDate` field says 10 a.m. today, so I am really confused by why that email is not being found by my first query. Can it be that the reply is not being seen as a "real" email by Java Mail (or IMAP for that matter)?

Here's my relevant code:

```java
private Message[] getMessagesSinceTimestampFromImapServer(Date since) throws MessagingException {
    Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    ReceivedDateTerm term = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, since);
    return emailFolder.search(term);
}
```

I am using Java 11 and IMAP to connect to an Office 365 inbox.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You're right, that might help. I added it.

Comment: Time-based search is not quite exact; there are always timezone issues wrt. server/client timezone, misunderstandings wrt. which time matters (sender, receiver). Happily all that is often best sidestepped by changing to a UID-based strategy: Keep track of the highest UID you've handled and handle all the mail that's arrived since. That will be precisely and reliably the messages with higher UIDs. And if you do that, a fifteen-second network outage that happens at the precise time your job runs won't make you lose an hour's mail, it'll be handled in the next run.

Comment: @arnt I've thought about this as well and will likely use this strategy. Nonetheless, I am sure that this is not a timezone issue, as I even get no results if I start the search at an entire day before the email actually arrived. What I'm interested in is if there is a bug in Java Mail that anyone is aware of or if there could be any server-side settings which could cause this behavior.

Comment: Turn on verbose debugging and look at the queries generated.  IMAP does not support ‘time-based’ search, only date based, with no reference to time zone, and it is up to the server to generate the response. Many different IMAP Server Implementations have particularly poor search implementations outside of the critical bits to support download-and-cache end-user email clients.